# Do I need PCR test results for the first leg of the flight? YYZ (Canada) -> FRA (Germany) -> BEG (Serbia), Lufthansa is saying different things

Tags: transit, canada, germany, covid-19, serbia

I am a Canadian citizen.

The clinics near me (smaller town in Canada) can take up to 48 hours to get my PCR test results. My flight is 34 hours after my planned PCR test, and Serbia requires me to have my PCR test result by valid 48 hours from when I enter I am thinking in worst case scenarios; Will Lufthansa ask me for my PCR test result on the leg from Toronto -> Frankfurt? I am worried that  in the case the clinic will not send my result by 30 hours, I am screwed. I should have it by the time I arrive in Serbia since that will be 46 hours (If my flight gets delayed they said up to 72 hours for my PCR test is valid).

I called Lufthansa twice, and one person said I need a PCR test, one person said I don't need one for boarding since Germany recognizes Canadian vaccine... I'm very confused.

Comment: Are both legs a single booking (one PNR)?

Comment: @Traveller yes all of them is one booking

Comment: @Traveller, do you think it will be an issue with serbian immigration if I get a RT-PCR test from the USA? I live on the Canada-US border and can go to a clinic in the us and be back in 20 minutes. The US clinic does tests in 3 hours and gives results.

Comment: I’m not sure but if you’ll transit airside in Frankfurt I think it’s possible that you will need the paperwork required to enter your *final* destination to board in Toronto. I’m not aware of any reason why a test from the US wouldn’t be accepted by Serbia (Timatic, the system used by airlines, shows no restriction on test location https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true). Frankfurt airport offers testing facilities landside AFAIK https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/flights-and-transfer/covid-19/coronavirus-testing-at-the-airport.html

Comment: @Traveller So I called the airline and they said it’s fine with them but they don’t know if Serbia will A CCEPT it when I reach there since it’s from a different departing country my embassy doesn’t really know either lol. I won’t have an issue with boarding

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its now outdated